# Unable to capture XPath of dynamic element - Selenium - C#(Visual Studio)

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

[The drop down list disappears on mouse click event on anywhere in the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwtbY.png)There is a Text box where in data is entered. On entering a drop down list pops out(kind of auto extender), with few options matching the entered text. I need to select one value form the list. But I am unable to capture the XPath, when I try to fetch the XPath, the list auto closes. How to capture such element?

HTML code for List:

```
<div id="citydiv" style="height: 120px; overflow: auto; position: absolute; width: 129px; visibility: hidden; left: 370px; top: 542px; z-index: 1000; display: none;" class="AutoExtender"></div>
```

Comment: Can you add some more html so it will give clearance

Comment: <input name="ctl00$cphpopup$tabContainer2$tabPnlAddressDetails$txtCity" type="text" maxlength="50" id="ctl00_cphpopup_tabContainer2_tabPnlAddressDetails_txtCity" class="mandsearchtxtbox" onkeypress="javascript:return ValidateInputAlphabeticValuesOnly(event);" onkeydown="return ValidateBackspCity(event);" style="width:127px;" autocomplete="off">

HTML for Text field

Comment: @NarendraRajput..could you specify what other html code should I add

Comment: Can you do one manual check : enter one value in text box after popping up dropdown just right click the first one and inspect the element and let me know the html code of that

Comment: Is it possible to share site url ?

Comment: No, its deployed on my system.

Comment: It didn't work. As soon as I click on the popup, it auto closes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the list from disappearing immediately by making use of Chrome dev-tools breakpoints.

Open the said page using google chrome

Open chrome developer tools (F12)

Click Sources > Event Listener Breakpoints > Mouse > enable the click event  
[image]

Focus on your textbox, type in something to make the auto-complete appear. If the debugger button appears before your auto-complete dropdown appears, just hit resume.

Once the list appears, click on the textbox so that the screen would freeze.

Once the screen is frozen, just click on the boxed icon below and click on the element you want to check. 
[image]

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE 1:**
This site is having a similar auto complete list when typing:
http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/autocomplete.php

I used the same steps above and I can inspect the elements.
[image]

If it still doesn't work for your page, try changing the click breakpoint to mousedown breakpoint.

**UPDATE 2:**
Try to do this, step by step:

1) enable mouseclick breakpoint using the steps above

2) click on your textbox - this will cause the screen to freeze.

3) hit resume until you can enter a value on the textbox

4) enter a value that will bring up the auto extender list

5) click on any available option - this should freeze the screen before the list disappears.

6) once the screen freezes, click on the inspect element icon highlighted below - this will unfreeze the screen but rightfully the auto extender list should stil be displayed
[image]

7) inspect the element by clicking. - this should freeze the screen again and while you can inspect the element / node you just clicked.

Comment: Clicking on resume, the page is still paused.

Comment: You can inspect the pop-up / auto complete list while the page is paused. WHen you're done, just disable the break point again.

Comment: Will you be able to update your question with screenshots into what's hapening when you try? Or if the site you're trying to access is public, please share the URL.

Comment: I updated my answer. I tried it on a public url having a similar feature and it was working. Try changing to mousedown breakpoint if click breakpoint does not work.

Comment: On mousedown breakpoint, I am able to resume the debugger, but when I rightclick on the list, it disappears.
On any mouse click, the list disappears.

Comment: Dont right click on the list. Use the element inspect icon in developer tools. I've updated the answer and highlighted the icon you need to click to inspect an element.

Comment: Glad I could help :)